# iTunes Connect, check total sales?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Is there a way using either iTunes connect or the API to check the total number of application sales for a particular app since release. I am just curious as ITC on the iPhone only seems to show 26 weeks when displaying totals, so it missed off the first 20+ weeks. (the app has been out for about 50 weeks).

I would just like to see **Release to Now, total sales = 4067** is this possible?

Comment: It does seem a bit daft, I am not after them storing 5gig of personal data, I just want them to store a long int or something and give me 4000.

Comment: Well 3 years after posting this it finally looks like Apple have revamped iTunes connect (Browser version not the mobile app) to allow a lot more control over viewing total sales, sales by app, sales by region etc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the Apple User Guide for the Financial Reports (available at bottom of iTunes Connect page):

> We do not store or regenerate the data after the periods have expired
>   (14 rolling days and 13 rolling weeks); you will need to download and
>   store this data on a regular basis if you intend to use it in the
>   future.

Comment: Thank you, so not having stored anything I will never know how many I have sold.

Comment: @fuzzygoat - You can still get the totals for earlier weeks and months, which will let you know the number of copies downloaded, you just won't have the fine granularity of the day-to-day sales.  An application like AppViz will do the synthesis of the various reports for you, making it fairly easy to arrive at a sum for your downloads.

Comment: Hi Brad, much appreciated, I downloaded "AppViz", but ultimately went with a free trail version of "AppFigures". I only need an estimate of total sales for now so will look at the pros-&-cons of each option when I need more timely data later in the year.

Comment: Wow can't believe it's true, but it is. Seriously, biggest company in the world can't total up your downloads. Should be a big number next to your app, unbelievable.

Comment: another way google does it better

Answer (score 19):

So the answer is: no.   It's so ridiculous -- 500GB of storage costs peanuts (yes I know IT storage costs more, redundancy, management, backups, archiving, blah blah, etc.), but it's still cheap.   Apple could keep a "total shipped" record and it wouldn't hurt them.

Comment: Even just storing the total would be helpful, you could live without all the region, price and other related analysis. The most basic question you ever get asked is "so, how many have you sold" its kind of mad that its difficult (or maybe even impossible) to find out.

Comment: Completely utterly retarded Apple policy.

Comment: Probably the reason is to limit the _server load_ and max table size.  Twitter doesn't allow infinite backscrolling (you have to "request your archive"), banks don't keep more than 18mos, I think _the only company_ that has respect for "infinite data" is Google.

Answer (score 12):

You might want to have a look in the section "Payments and Financial Reports" within iTunes Connect. There's an overview of your total sales within the "Summary" tab . However this view is only updated on a monthly basis.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It's right where he says.  In Payments instead of Sales.  "Summary->Trends->Total Units Sold"  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Doesn't tell you information for individual apps.

Comment: But this doesn't show anything if its a free app right ?

Comment: In this graph in the upper left you can change it to (in my case) EUR, then you can see how much you made (in case you have free apps, or several apps with different costs.)

Answer (score 2):

From the "Sales and Trends" iTunes Connect FAQ

How long are reports available for download? 
 Weekly Report: Thirteen (13) rolling weeks prior to the current week are available for download.

Daily Report: Seven (7) rolling days prior to the current day are available for download.

Information is only available for the periods following the date when the reporting was activated in iTunes Connect. Reporting is generally activated prior to any sales on the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store you own records, Apple only stores a limited amount for documented time periods.

But if you look at your financial reports, they may contain data covering earlier months.

Added: In fact, for the correct sales or download numbers, one should only use the monthly financial reports, as Apple says that the daily and weekly trend reports should only be used for estimation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS iTunesConnect app will show you data for the prior 26 (and 13 and 5 etc) weeks. This can help if you missed some weekly data from the ITC www mothership.

Answer (score 2):

There is now. We (appfigures.com) are actually in the process of testing functionality that uses all of the data sets Apple gives (along with some magic) to give you an accurate all-time total for all metrics (downloads, sales, updates, etc).

We have this in beta right now so if you'd like to give it a try contact us directly through the site and we'll get you in. We're hoping to make this available to all users very soon.

FYI - This new feature works even if you've just opened a new appFigures account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't rely on Apple, I just check my Google analytics report for total uniques and just infer from that.

Comment: hay lan, we are not talking about android. so please be sure about what u r talking

Comment: Sandy, you can put GA tracking inside a native iOS native app.

Answer (score 0):

Now, apple provides reports until 2008.
So, i downloaded the previous years, months, weeks and days reports and concatenated them together with excel to get the total downloads and updates using excel filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can view sales by day, week, month and year by clicking the date in the top right hand corner of the Sales and Trends report for your app in iTunes Connect.

it seems to go back a few years, so should show you the figures you need.

Answer (score 0):

it seems apple has updated the available periods as below from [AppStoreReportingInstructions](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf) :

> Reports are only available at certain times and only retained for
>   certain periods. Reports should be downloaded regularly for your
>   records.
>
> • Daily reports include data for the previous day in the selected territory and are retained for 30 days.
>
> • Weekly reports include data starting on Monday and ending on Sunday of the previous week. Weekly reports are available on Mondays
>   and retained for 26 weeks.
>
> • Monthly reports are available five days after the month’s end date and are retained for 12 months.
>
> • Yearly reports are available six days after the year’s end date and are retained indefinitely.
>
> • All reports are generally available by 9:00 a.m. Pacific Time (PT).
>
> Apple does not store or regenerate the data after these periods have expired.